# Monotouch SIGHUP Error, unable to open in Xcode

Tags: xamarin.ios

since three days i have the monotouch personal edition.
I developed an app in monotouch evaluation and now i want to run it in the personal edition.

My problem is to open the monotouch project in xcode. There is an error while create the xcode package. Additionally i added an screenshot of the error.
(http://digitale-mediengestaltung.com/W4U/Foto.JPG)

When i try to open an simple helloworld app in xcode, its run.

Thank you for support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer but I solved the problem!

There were spaces in the path to project directory.

But I add the chat to my bookmarks.

Want to test the compatibility and... I'm still waiting for my apple dev enrollment

Comment: Ok :) nice to hear that, yeah apple takes a little to get you all set to development and also to aprove apps lol, Have fun with MonoTouch its a really great product if you come from .NET world is the best thing that could happen to iOS development :) btw if that was your solution for your question dont forget to mark your question as solved :D cheers Alex

Answer (score 0):

i cant really help you directly with that but you can go to IRC and ask directly to Mono Team they have a really great support by going to http://monotouch.net/Chat.

Btw why would you like to open a monotouch project on xcode? just wondering